# How to make a custom sequence within developer studio in wso2 - esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

If I have a more complex code within my sequence where I can not do only with using existing mediators, can I create a sequence with a custom java logic ? how do u support it within dev - studio ?

Comment: Please check also https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS380/FAQ#FAQ-HowcanIwriteaCustommediatorforWSO2ESBusingDeveloperStudio?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write custom mediators for **WSO2 ESB**.

This is all what you want to know about [custom mediators](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Writing+a+WSO2+ESB+Mediator).

This is a [sample](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Sample+380%3A+Writing+your+own+Custom+Mediation+in+Java) custom mediator explained.

Hope this helps.